# Why did The One needed to choose an unequal number of males and females?

Tags: the-matrix

The Architect says that The One must choose 23 people (16 female, 7 male) to create new Zion.

> After which, you will be required to select from the Matrix 23 individuals - 16 female, 7 male - to rebuild Zion.

At first, it seems unfair for males, but again, wouldn't females go haywire if current nature (of sense of security in relationship) is taken into account?

Why exactly this unequal number was chosen? Even if you see females more important in reproduction, you just need one male (or, an extra for backup, in case).

Comment: Because The One was a Mormon? *"..you just need one male"*  More if you want any genetic variability in the Y chromosome. *"(or, an extra for backup, in case)."*  Or add frozen sperm ampoules, for backup..  Let's face it, from a 'propagate the species' POV - once you have sperm, men are redundant.

Comment: "wouldn't females go haywire if current nature (of sense of security in relationship) is taken into account?"

misogynist much?

Comment: @revenant No way... Take it positively, please. I am a good guy.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt theres a canonical answer so

In universe the machines most likely based the number of males and females on an algorithm that ensures genetic viability of the new Zion while taking into account the people that will be freed from the matrix by the new Zionists as well as many other variables.

Out of universe they probably just made up some numbers they thought sounded good.

Comment: It must be a made up numbers, all studies on the minimal viable genetic pool give bigger numbers (above 80 seems to be a minimum...) https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn1936-magic-number-for-space-pioneers-calculated/

Comment: @maxpnj you seem to be forgetting that Zion gets destroyed every 100 years or so, so the genetic diversity required is for a civilization being healthy for only a century, not for tens of thousands of years like the 80+ study recommends